# Converting from hexadecimal to decimal number in C

Tags: c

I am doing the exercise in the C Programming language book, and exercise 2-3 asked us to write a function htoi to convert a hexadecimal number to decimal number.

This is the code I wrote, however when it runs, it always show that my hexadecimal number is illegal.

Please help!

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

  int htoi (char s[]);
  int main() {
      printf("The decimal number is %d\n", htoi("0x134"));
      return 0;
  }
  int htoi (char s[]) {
      int j;   /* counter for the string */
      int temp;  /* temp number in between conversion */
      int number; /* the converted number */
      int ishex;  /* if the number is a valid hexadecimal number */
      char c;

      number = 0;
      temp = 0;
      ishex = FALSE;

      if (s[0] == '0' && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X')) {
          ishex = TRUE;
      }
      else {
          ishex = FALSE;
          printf("This is not valid hexadecimal number.\n");
          return number = 0;
      }
      if (ishex == TRUE) {
          for (j = 2; (c = s[j]) != EOF; ++j) {
              if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
                  temp = c - '0';
              else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f')
                  temp = 10 + c - 'a';
              else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F')
                  temp = 10 + c - 'A';
              else {
                  printf("This is a illegal hexadecimal number.\n");
                  ishex = FALSE;
                  return 0;
              }
              number = number * 16 + temp;
          }
      }      
      return number;
  }
```

Comment: `(c = s[j]) != EOF;` --> `(c = s[j]) != '\0';`

Comment: What is EOF defined as?

Comment: Is `++j` the right choice?

Comment: I used '\0' and that solved my problem, Thanks! BTW, what's the difference between '\0' and EOF?

Comment: EOF is an integer, which cannot be represented as a char. It's there to accomplish out of band signaling, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: `EOF` is used to represent an end-of-file. If you look it up in the appropriate standard header file, I think it's value happens to be `-1`. `'\0'` is a null character, used to terminate a string. It's a `char` with value `0`. Two completely different things. I believe your C books tells you about them.

Comment: Basic debugging technique: report the value that causes trouble.  For example: `printf("This is an illegal hexadecimal number (%d = '%c').\n", c, c);` would tell you what character is being analyzed when the error is generated, which would make it a whole lot easier for you to work out what the problem is.  I didn't bother with checking whether the value is printable.  Helpful diagnostics help you — indeed, they'd probably save you from having to ask on SO.

Comment: @BobbySacamano How does C99 or C11 guarantee that `sizeof(int) > sizeof(char)`?

Comment: @Rhymoid I was going off of this: https://www.seebs.net/c/c_tcn4e.html He addresses this at the bottom of the page 348 section. I guess the wording of my comment was a little off though; it should have been that EOF is distinct from any value returned from reading characters from a file.

Answer (score 0):

A string is a sequence of characters that terminates at the first `'\0'` character. That means `"0x134"` terminates with a `'\0'` character value, not an `EOF` value.

You are operating on a sequence of characters that you expect to be terminated by an `EOF` value, but that is simply not possible. I'll explain why later... Suffice to say for now, the string `"0x134"` contains no `EOF` value.

Your loop reaches the string-terminating `'\0'`, which isn't in the range `0..9`, `a..f` or `A..F` and so this branch executes:

```
          else {
              printf("This is a illegal hexadecimal number.\n");
              ishex = FALSE;
              return 0;
          }
```

Perhaps you meant to write your loop like so:

```
for (j = 2; (c = s[j]) != '\0'; ++j) {
    /* SNIP */
}
```

---

I promised to explain what is wrong with expecting `EOF` to exist as a character value. Assuming an `unsigned char` is 8 bits, `getchar` can return one of 256 character values, and it will return them as a *positive* `unsigned char` value... **OR** it can return the *negative* `int` value `EOF`, corresponding to an error or end-of-file.

Confused? In an empty file, there are no characters... Yet if you try to read a character from the file, you will get `EOF` every time, in spite of there being no characters. Hence, `EOF` is not a character value. It's an `int` value, and should be treated as such *before* you attempt to convert the value to a character, like so:

```
int c = getchar();
if (c == EOF) {
    /* Here, c is NOT A CHARACTER VALUE! *
     * It's more like an error code ...  *
     * XXX: Break or return or something */
}
else {
    /* Here, c IS a character value, ... *
     * so the following conversion is ok */
    char ch = c;
}
```

---

On another note, `c >= '0' && c <= '9'` will evaluate truthfully when c is one of the digits in the range `0..9`... This is a requirement from the C standard

Neither `c >= 'a' && c <= 'f'` nor `c >= 'A' && c <= 'F'` are required to evaluate truthfully under any circumstance, however. It happens to work on your system, because you are using ASCII which contains all of the lowercase letters in one contiguous block, and all of the uppercase letters in another contiguous block. C does not require that ASCII be the character set.

If you want this code to work *portably*, you might consider something like:

```
char alpha_digit[] = "aAbBcCdDeEfF";
if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
    c -= '0';
}
else if (strchr(alpha_digit, c)) {
    c = 10 + (strchr(alpha_digit, c) - alpha_digit) / 2;
}
else {
    /* SNIP... XXX invalid digit */
}
```